# Is JavaScript console vulnerable to XSS

Tags: web-application, appsec, xss, javascript

Assume the content of the `name` variable below is controlled by an attacker. Is this line of code vulnerable to XSS?

```
console.log(name)
```

When I send an injection in `name` variable I see its value printed by `console.log` as a URL encoded string, and it does not get interpreted as a script tag format. Is there a way to exploit this to XSS attack ?

Comment: in which language have you crafted these lines ?

Comment: javascript, it's inside a javascript function

Comment: i tried to inject the following payload: fname=alert(1); but it didnt work

Comment: Script injection doesn’t apply to `console.log` output…

Answer (score 4):

No the exact code you have posted is not vulnerable to XSS.

Now if you are writing `first_name` to the page anywhere it could be a [reflected XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_%28OTG-INPVAL-001%29) or maybe a [DOM based XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  But the tiny piece code you have posted is not a vulnerability

Answer (score -5):

It is useless to try to find an XSS vulnerability within pure JavaScript code.

XSS vulernabilities are useful when the website offers to you the opportunity to interact with PHP/MySQL inputs/URLs. We can not talk about XSS in your case.

Comment: Dnakki your answer is completely wrong and quite harmful. OF COURSE there can be XSS in javascript-only code. Obviously XSS is not just about PHP (even though it is very common there), and it has absolutely nothing to do with MySQL (or any other database for that matter). I suggest you read up a bit on so-called "DOM-Based XSS" or "client-side XSS".